# how to convert csv file to multi sheet in excel

Tags: oracle, csv, sqlplus, xls

i have export db_table in CSV file. I need to convert it in a multi sheet file in excel,

somebody can hel me ?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What programming language do you use? Show your efforts so far ..

Comment: What will go in the multiple sheets? It sounds like your csv file only contains one set of data. Also is your question how to convert a csv file, or how to create an Excel file directly from the database?

Comment: my question is; how to create one excel file with multi sheet from two or more csv files ? thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Would have loved to have a detailed question here. 
But it seems that you have converted a table into csv file and are looking to convert that csv into a multi sheet excel (xlsx). 
You can do this by just using the "Save As" function in excel once you open the csv and then saving the sheet in an "xlsx" format. 
Let me know if you need any other help and do explain the question in detail for a quicker turnaround :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i have three csv file and i need to convert in one excel file with 3 or more sheet. now i'm tring to do it with python.. i will post my code in the afternoon